# Django Admin проверка условие при добавлении .

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Есть класс `Bill` в django-admin нужно поставить условие, если для значение `Card` выбран элемент (если это не Блан ор Нулл) то невозможно было выбрать чекбокс так и в обратном распорядке. Именно во время добавление если чекбокс перешел в True то message с ошибкой о том что выберите один из двух вариантов. Буду благодарен и за информацию о том где искать решение.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Şəxs kart nömrəsi")
    survey = models.BooleanField(default=False,  verbose_name="Müayinə")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно объявить свою форму для админки и делать в ней валидацию:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class BillForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bill

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BillForm, self).clean()
        if cleaned_data.get('card') and cleaned_data.get('survey'):
            raise ValidationError(u'Нужно выбрать что-то одно')
        return cleaned_data


@admin.register(Bill)
class BillAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BillForm
```